# Can I update the extern for AbortController in the Google closure compiler?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I'm working on an application that uses Fetch in the browser. The compiler (v20221102) complains:

```
.../src/main/js/src/Fetch.js:766:29: WARNING - [JSC_WRONG_ARGUMENT_COUNT] Function AbortController.prototype.abort: called with 1 argument(s). Function requires at least 0 argument(s) and no more than 0 argument(s).
  766|             setTimeout(() => controller.abort(reason), wait);`
```

AFAICT, this is because the extern for AbortController in `externs/browser/w3c_abort.js` (in the Closure compiler source) defines:

```
AbortController.prototype.abort = function() {};
```

Is there any way I can override or extend this prototype to avoid the warnings? AFAICT, the browser implementation of AbortController now allows a `reason` to be passed to the abort method.